# C# HttpWebRequest vs HttpClient vs RestSharp

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient, restsharp

I'm trying to send a simple post request in 3 different ways, first two are failing with 400 Bad Request, only RestSharp works. I would say the body of the request and the headers are set in the same way, so I don't understand what's wrong.

#### Using `HttpWebRequest`

```
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";
httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = $"Bearer {token}";
httpRequest.Headers["Client_Id"] = clientId;
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(json);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

#### Using `HttpClient`

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Client_Id", clientId);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("gzip"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.AcceptEncoding.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue("deflate"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/x-json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/javascript"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/xml"));

    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var result = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
}
```

#### raw in Fiddler

```
POST https://uri HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
Content-Type: application/json
Client_Id: 123456
Authorization: Bearer token
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: uri
Content-Length: 314
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

#### Using `RestClient`

```
var restClient = new RestClient(uri);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("Client_Id", clientId);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");
request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = restClient.Execute(request);
```

#### raw in Fiddler

```
POST https://uri HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/json, text/x-json, text/javascript, application/xml, text/xml
Content-Type: application/json
Client_Id: 123456
Authorization: Bearer token
User-Agent: RestSharp/106.12.0.0
Host: uri
Content-Length: 314
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: User fiddler to determine the difference between your requests and any future issues, though apart from a missing Content-Type they all look fairly similar

Comment: I updated the post with the raw data from Fiddler for httpclient and restsharp

Comment: Why do you have `Expect: 100-continue` in headers for standard clients? It isn't usual for them to set that header automatically. Server could not understand that header and cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Part of HttpClient: StringContent adds charset values end of Content-Type like `application/json; charset=utf-8` so it could cause 400 error.

You can remove it by using this code `content .Headers.ContentType.CharSet = "";`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work, I update the post with the raw data I got from Fiddler on both requests

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great article that you can check regarding the comparison between HttpClient and RestSharp - [HttpClientVsRestSharp](https://code-maze.com/httpclient-vs-restsharp/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You can resume here the article, and keep the reference ;)